# buck small signal modelling

Tags: mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, buck, small-signal, closed-loop

I have a synchronous buck converter and my inductor current looks like this:-

[image]

1. To add voltage-mode closed loop control, I need to do the small signal modelling of the converter. I am a bit confused if this would be called DCM (I think not as in DCM the current would have to be zero for some time *not negligibly small*.)
2. I know how to do the CCM, DCM small signal modelling in a buck converter, but I am having trouble writing the equations during the dead-time. So far, I have only got the equations for the times when either one of the switches are ON. I need help with the dead-time part.

Thank you!

Comment: TI has an app note with all the design equations for buck, boost, CUK, sepic, zeta, flyback etc.: https://www.ti.com/seclit/ug/slyu036/slyu036.pdf

Comment: Have a look at my seminars APEC 2013, 2014 and 2019 that you can download from my [webpage](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Spice.htm). To model the buck in DCM voltage- or current-mode control, you need the corresponding model of the PWM switch. The other (quicker) option for you is to use on of my latest 60+ SIMPLIS templates that I posted [here](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) and extract the small-signal response immediately after the cycle-by-simulation.

Comment: @VerbalKint Yes I have looked at your simulation templates before, they're extremely useful for a beginner in SIMPLIS like me! Unfortunately, in this case I have to derive the equations by hand right now, so I was hoping the deadtime part could be clarified in equations.

Comment: You mean you want to include the duty ratio \$d_3\$? This is done in the DCM PWM switch model that I derived for my next book due in June.